# error: unknown field ‘Hash’ in ‘rsa.PSSOptions’

Tags: go, gccgo

So, I am building docker that uses rsa module of golang. I am using golang by building gcc, which has gccgo.

```
linux-l853:~/docker # go version
go version gccgo (GCC) 5.0.0 20141113 (experimental) linux/ppc64
```

Now, when I am building it, I get the following error:

```
github.com/endophage/gotuf/signed
vendor/src/github.com/endophage/gotuf/signed/verifiers.go:102:50: error: unknown field ‘Hash’ in ‘rsa.PSSOptions’
  opts := rsa.PSSOptions{SaltLength: sha256.Size, Hash: crypto.SHA256}
                                                  ^
```

Wherein I know that Hash field is defined in rsa.PSSOptions. Any idea why am I getting this error?

TIA.

Comment: gccgo isn't up to date with the official go implementation. Is there any particular reason you're trying to use gccgo?

Comment: Yeah, the arch I am working on isn't supported by go. Has the rsa package been added recently? Is there anywhere where I can find that information?

Comment: It looks like gcc 5 should be up to date with go1.4, which has that field. If PSSOptions is missing Hash, it means that package was built from something before go1.4.